# Select mssql 2008 data but not display all using php in ubuntu server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ubuntu

I have SQL server 2008 and I want to display data using php from ubuntu server.
After run a web app, it displays only 22158 rows from 34675 rows. Here is my code:

```
$qry = "select contract_no from contracts";
$result = mssql_query($qry,$con);
while($rs=mssql_fetch_array($result))
{
print "$rs[contract_no]<br>";
}
?>
```

It displays only 22158 records from which actually the database has 34675 records.

Comment: I think issue is with your execution time. Put this is top of your script `set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but wondering, just put it on top of my php file right?.

Comment: Well, I tried your code but still got the same result.

Comment: yes. You can also put it just before your query.

Comment: Add `ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');` in top of your file now and don't remove `set_time_limit(0);` from it.

Comment: Still the same. My table has around 25 columns and some of them contains datetime and even "Null" value. Could this be the effect of the query?

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a memory limit set in `php.ini`.  I'm not sure this is the issue you are running into, but its worth mentioning and hopefully helpful to mention.  To test this theory use `mysql_unbuffered_query()` in lieu of `mssql_query()`.  If you get all 34675 records with this change then this is your issue.

Comment: When using mssql_unbuffered_query, it just display nothing.

Comment: Also, I have adjusted my php.ini already, still get the same result

Comment: When using the same command in sql server management studio, it  displays 34675 records, I have no idea now.

Comment: can you do a mysql_num_rows($result) on your page to verify $result is getting 34675 rows

Comment: Sorry, not mysql. It's mssql and I do mssql_num_rows($result) which I get the number of 22158

Comment: My table has around 25 columns and some of them contains datetime and even "Null" value. Could this be the effect of the query?

Comment: without seeing your data its impossible to know for sure.  Try this, use if($$rs[contract_no] == null) to check each row before printing.  In the case that it is null print "NULL" and see if this accounts for your missing rows.

Comment: seems that it's the primary key so no null value in this column

Comment: when i use where datetime = '2015-08-07 00:00:00', it returns 0

Comment: Finally I found myself making a mistake. This is because of multiple database connection in my config file. Thanks to all comments and answers.